# Infopath Rich Text Box - add DEFAULT value in Rich Text format?

Tags: infopath

How can I add defaut RICH text to a Rich Text Box in an InfoPath form?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with the out of the box tools like SharePoint Designer or InfoPath. It would require code.

If it is a Browser form (and not a list form) you may want to consider the QRules add-in by Qdabra. It contains a command (with code behind) that can copy rich text. You could have a template item somewhere that contains the default rich text. Upon form load you could look up the template item and use the QRules command to copy the rich text field into the current form's rich text field.

If you're using a list form this won't work. You can pre-populate a rich text field, but not including formatting, just text.